# c++ math/hex question

Tags: c++, math, hex

Sorry if this sounds a bit 'noobish' but I don't know c++ and I was looking at some code for the perlin noise, trying to figure it out when I came across

`& 0x7fffffff`

and

`(n << 13) ^ n;`

and I have no idea what those mean. I do know that `0x7fffffff` is hex, but I don't know what the `&` means *Any help?*

Comment: That's called [bit twiddling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_twiddling). It's just like regular arithmetic operations, except these operators pertain directly to the bits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first expression is a bitmask.  It basically clears out the upper bit of the number, or equivalently computes a mod of the number over 2^31.

The second expression is a shift, followed by an xor.  In arithmetic it would be the same thing as multiplying n by 2^13, then flipping all the bits that are common between the shifted version and itself.  Its purpose in the perlin noise code is to compute a procedural spatial hash of the x,y coordinates so that they can be used to seed the noise generator.

This same type of technique is used in a lot of procedural content to create dynamically varying psuedo random number generators that vary deterministically in space.  These hashes are basically meant to be complicated, difficult to predict, nearly random functions and are usually discovered with a mixture of theory, guess work and experimentation.  As a result, I would not recommend thinking too hard about why it is using that specific formula in this case.

Comment: so like     `n=n*2^13; t=(longnumbers)/2^31;` ?

Comment: @user677756: Not quite.  The first expression would be t = (long numbers) % pow(2, 31).  The second expression would be n = (n * pow(2, 13)) + n - (all the bits that got carried when adding)

Comment: Ok,that makes more sense but one last question, what exactly are bits and how will I find the ones that got carried when adding? ( I don't know any c, just lua,php and html, sorry )

Comment: @user677756:  Wikipedia is your friend:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Answer (score 4):

***`&` is a  bit wise AND operator in C++***

The bitwise AND operator (&) compares each bit of the first operand to the corresponding bit of the second operand. If both bits are 1, the corresponding result bit is set to 1. Otherwise, the corresponding result bit is set to 0.

```
     11111111 11110000  
   & 00000000 01100011
     _________________
     00000000 01100000
```

***`<<` is bit wise left shift operator in C++***

The << operator shifts its first operand left by a number of bits given by its second operand, filling in new 0 bits at the right.

```
    0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 << 2
    _____________________
    0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

***`^` is Ex-Or operator in C++***

The bitwise-exclusive-OR operator compares each bit of its first operand to the corresponding bit of its second operand. If one bit is 0 and the other bit is 1, the corresponding result bit is set to 1. Otherwise, the corresponding result bit is set to 0.

```
     0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0
   ^ 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
   ___________________  
     0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

So, `& 0x7fffffff` sets bit 31 of the 32-bit integer to zero and leaves other bits with values they had.

`(n << 13) ^ n` `n` is left-shifted with `13` and the result is XORed with `n`.

Comment: but if it was some number AND 0x7fffffff, wouldn't that always return 0x7fffffff? and thanks for explaining the <<

Comment: Okay, let's shorten 0x7fffffff to 0x7f just for now. So let's say you're doing 151 AND 0x7f - in binary this is 10010111 AND 01111111. The result, by taking all the bits that are 1 in both operands, is 00010111. What has it done? It's MASKED OUT the first bit. Your answer is 151 with the first bit removed. The answer is 23.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is bitwise AND operator. So `& 0x7fffffff` stripping off the signed bit from an 32 bit integer.  That means, it makes the leftmost bit of `int` zero.

And in the second one, first `n` is left-shifted with 13 using `<<` operator which is left-shift operator, and the result of this expression used in XOR operation with `n` itself.

Answer (score 0):

The symbols `&`, `<<`, and `^` are called **operators**.  There is a Wikipedia page that lists [C/C++ operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) so you can learn about the names of those operators and then search Google for more information.

The `0x7fffffff` is an integer written in hex (base 16) notation. The `0x` prefix means it is hex.

The `n` is probably the name of an integer variable defined a few lines above the line you quoted.

The parentheses serve to group expressions together, so in your example they guarantee that n gets shifted left by 13 bits BEFORE it gets XOR'd with n.  Without the parentheses, the order of operations would be determined by the [operator precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm), (which in your example happens to give the same result).

Answer (score 0):

`& 0x7fffffff` means set bit 31 of the (presumed) 32-bit integer to zero, preserving the values of bits 0 through 30; IOW, make the 32-bit integer be positive; IOW, take the abs val of the integer.

`(n << 13) ^ n;` means shift `n` left by 13 bits, then xor that shifted value with the original value of `n`.

HTH